# Disallow Facebook to crawl image as post thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

is there a chance to disallow facebook to crawl a specific image as post thumbnail? I know the og:image possibility, but in case there is no og:image specified on the page, the crawler will looking for an alternatively image by itselfs. This is a bit annoying, because not in all cases the selected image is a good choice.

Regards,
Tim

Comment: the best choice is to always provide an og:image

Comment: Yes of course, I'm asking this because of I'm developing a WordPress plugin and want to provide a solution for those, who not have an og:image defined in their WordPress blog. The plugin provides a weather map and a lot of times, facebook crals this picture as thumbnail...

Comment: how about a placeholder og:image for that?

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility... Otherwise I'ts also good to know, that there is currently no other way to do it. Thank's!